# Undefined Method 'NameOfField' for #<Model:0x000...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm totally stumped on this error. Would really appreciate some help :).

To reproduce the error, you can pull the program from https://github.com/WaleyChen/twitter_clone. Then run 'bundle exec rspec spec/'.

I have an rspec test for my controller defined as:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FrontpageController do
  render_views # render the views inside the controller tests, so not just test the actions

  describe "GET 'frontpage'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'frontpage'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'frontpage'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Twitter")
    end
  end

end
```

When I run my rspec tests, I get the following error:

```
Failures:

1) FrontpageController GET 'frontpage' should be successful
 Failure/Error: get 'frontpage'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `full_name' for #<User:0x007fbfce43dce0>
 # ./app/views/frontpage/frontpage.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_frontpage_frontpage_html_erb___4518234645475110659_70230885952360'
 # ./app/views/frontpage/frontpage.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_frontpage_frontpage_html_erb___4518234645475110659_70230885952360'
 # ./spec/controllers/frontpage_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) FrontpageController GET 'frontpage' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: get 'frontpage'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `full_name' for #<User:0x007fbfcc99a410>
 # ./app/views/frontpage/frontpage.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_frontpage_frontpage_html_erb___4518234645475110659_70230885952360'
 # ./app/views/frontpage/frontpage.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_frontpage_frontpage_html_erb___4518234645475110659_70230885952360'
 # ./spec/controllers/frontpage_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the controller:

```
class FrontpageController < ApplicationController
  def frontpage
    @user = User.new
    @sign_up = User.new
  end

  def sign_up
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the view, that's causing the error:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url =>"sign_up" do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :full_name, :placeholder => "Full name" %>
  </br>
  <%= form.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
  </br>
  <%= form.text_field :pw, :placeholder => "Password" %>
  </br>
  <%= form.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Username" %>
  </br>
  <%= form.submit "Sign up" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Here's schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111106084309) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "pw"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Post user.rb and schema.rb; it looks like `full_name` is not a column or method on your model.

Comment: Does accessing the `full_name` attribute work in the rails console?

Comment: it works in the rail console, i was able to do user = User.new then user.full_name with no problems

Comment: Well that is something pretty weird. I'll be thinking about it, if no one comes with anything, you might want to try [Pry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) to debug the code.

Comment: Does the test database exist? And in it, does the `users` table exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your test database is up to date with all the migrations:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

However, you may have a problem with that as your migrations are broken; you have two migrations named "CreateUsers" which Rails will complain about. It looks like you should delete the more recent one, and then uncomment the `t.string :email` line in the original one.

Also, if you use `bundle exec rake rspec` instead of `bundle exec rspec spec` it'll make sure your database migrations are up to date before running the tests. I just cloned your repo and did this and it passed the tests just fine.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! I deviated from the book I was learning from and didn't know I had to reupdate my test database. THANKS AGAIN!!!! :D