# RSpec file upload raises 'undefined method' for header row

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, rspec

I have a rails 3.2.16 app that has a model and controller to upload a csv file that contains a list of customer details. In the app itself this works fine, however I can't get the test to work.

I basically get an error that says

```
undefined method 'first_name,last_name,address_1,address_2,city .... etc.'
```

So it is trying to use the first line of the csv file as a method ... ?

The files I am using are shown below

spec (the commented out lines show things that I have tried along the way having seen other issues in SO)

```
it "upload a file with correct properties" do
  #include Rack::Test::Methods
  # @file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/cust-imp-good.csv'), 'text/csv')
  @file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/cust-imp-good.csv'), 'text/csv')

  post :create, :customer_import => @file
  response.should be_success
end
```

uploader model

```
class CustomerImport #< ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :file

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    debugger
    attributes.each { |name, value| send("#{name}=", value) }
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def save
    if imported_customers.map(&:valid?).all?
      valid_ids = true

      dive_shop_ids = DiveShop.ids_array
      discount_level_ids = DiscountLevel.ids_array

      imported_customers.each_with_index do |customer, index|
        if !dive_shop_ids.include?(customer.dive_shop_id)
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: dive_shop_id #{customer.dive_shop_id} is not valid"
          valid_ids = false
        end
        if !discount_level_ids.include?(customer.discount_level_id)
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: discount_level_id #{customer.discount_level_id} is not valid"
          valid_ids = false
        end        
      end

      if valid_ids
        imported_customers.each(&:save!)
        return_val = imported_customers.count
      else
        false
      end

    else
      imported_customers.each_with_index do |customer, index|
        customer.errors.each do |message|
          errors.add :base, "Row #{index+2}: #{message}"
        end
      end
      false
    end

  end

  def imported_customers
    @imported_customers ||= ImportRecord.load_imported_records("Customer", file)
  end


end
```

From the error shown below I can see that it is failing in the initializer. Although if I put a debugger in there the initializer looks to be OK.

Output from debugger inside initializer

```
rdb:1 attributes
Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x0000000b089a98 @content_type="text/csv", @original_filename="cust-imp-good.csv", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/cust-imp-good.csv20131212-26548-ynutnh>>
rdb:1
```

Output from rspec failure message

```
Failures:

  1) CustomerImportsController POST 'create' upload a file with correct properties
     Failure/Error: post :create, :customer_import => @file
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `first_name,last_name,address1,address2,address3,city,state,country,postcode,telephone,email,dob,local_contact,emergency_name,emergency_number,dive_shop_id,discount_level_id
       =' for #<CustomerImport:0x0000000a5f7580>
     # ./app/models/customer_import.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
     # ./app/models/customer_import.rb:10:in `initialize'
     # ./app/controllers/customer_imports_controller.rb:14:in `new'
     # ./app/controllers/customer_imports_controller.rb:14:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/customer_imports_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

any help would be much appreciated I tried the solution shown in [Undefined Method 'NameOfField' for #<Model:0x000...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026074/undefined-method-nameoffield-for-model0x000) i.e rake: db:test:prepare and bundle exec rspec . but this didn't work either

**EDIT to include controller code**

```
class CustomerImportsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter do
    @menu_group = "diveshop"
  end

  def new
    @customer_import = CustomerImport.new
  end

  def create

    if params[:customer_import] != nil

      @customer_import = CustomerImport.new(params[:customer_import])
      return_value = @customer_import.save # need to add @customer_import.file here
      if return_value != false    
        addauditlog("A bulk import of customers was carried out")
        redirect_to customers_url, notice: "Imported #{return_value} customers successfully."
      else
        render :new
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "You have not selected a file"
      redirect_to new_customer_import_url
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In creating the new model instance, your controller seems to have passed a hash as a parameter with a key whose value is the first line of the csv file. You'll need to share the controller code and the first line of the file you've updated in order to be able to confirm that and provide more information.

Comment: Have added that code. The first line of the file is exactly as the error shows